# Matrix is singular

Tags: ltspice, frequency, high-frequency

I have checked the other questions concerning this topic, but I can not seem to understand it. Here is my circuit. For some reason, it always says Matrix is singular. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are Ue and Ua connected to anything?

Comment: Hormis an offset in voltage for Ue, this should work. If this was not working, then one could not wire some use of 'transmission lines" (RF toroidal transformers) ... as some "transformers" used to raise impedance ratios ... See this for reference https://www.highfrequencyelectronics.com/Dec07/HFE1207_GrebennikovPart1.pdf

Answer (score 4):

LTspice tends to not like things having no path to ground, and the load side of the transmission line has no path to ground.

You would think it's like a piece of coax and grounding one side will suffice, but it doesn't. Try adding a ground on the load side. If you don't want that side directly grounded you can add a high value resistor (1E12) to ground. You can also use a capacitor or inductor to ground.

Another option is to set [GSHUNT](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_OPTIONS_Set_simulator_options.htm) to some very small value. This causes LTspice to add a shunt conductance from every node to ground. You do this by adding a directive to your schematic such as:

**.OPTION GSHUNT = 1E-12**

There may be side effects with this as it affects every node, you can try changing the value to see it makes any difference in your results.

This error also happens if you try to do an AC analysis on a power transformer with an AC voltage source feeding the primary but no path from the primary to ground.

The error doesn't appear to occur when doing a transient analysis.

Comment: Isn't it RSHUNT? It doesn't seem intuitive that they'd call it "GSHUNT" and then ask you put a value in ohms. Otherwise, it should be 1e-12.

Comment: @ErnestoG In LTspice using RSHUNT will give you an 'unrecognized option' error. You're right about the 1E-12 though, corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Spice wants to produce node voltages. But as I'm sure you already know, a voltage requires two points as \$V_{_\text{AB}}=\int_{_\text{A}}^{^\text{B}}\mathscr{E}_x\:\text{d}x\$. So actually, voltages are always the difference between two points and cannot be *"just a node voltage."* But simple matrices have scalar values. So Spice needs you to specify *some node* in the circuit as its **"zero reference."** That way, all those nice matrices can actually just hold a simple scalar that is referenced to that node and everyone is happy, again.

Unfortunately, *the other side* (the opposite port) isn't galvanically connected in your case. So Spice sees the nodes on the other port without a galvanic connection to the required ground (zero) reference.

Spice wants every node with a galvanic path to ground, so the cheap and easy way to give Spice a clue is to tie something on the opposite port side (and pretty much anything there, as it doesn't matter what) to ground using a very large-valued resistor.

For example,

[image]

should get the job done.

This won't disturb the goals you have (much.) But it gives Spice what it needs so that its matrices and algorithms can *feel safe*, again.

The only decision you need to make is to decide which node at the other port's subcircuit you'd prefer to see as a zero value. That's the one you tie through a large-valued resistor to ground.

Comment: This is automatically done by microcap simulator (inserting a 1T resistor where it is needed) ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Yes, I think when I was first reading about Spice simulators (might have been ORCAD's?), I remember seeing the comment that it would add a resistor to ground at EVERY node. So I'm sure that's a common situation. Apparently, LTspice doesn't force-fit that without the .OPTION being used. (And there may be good reason NOT to use GSHUNT in every circuit.)

Comment: Right @Jonk I already used microcap since the beginning year 1980 ... this option has always been used as a "default" option (a very common problem).

Comment: This answer is confusing because it repeatedly talks about transformers when the circuit in question has a transmission line and no transformers.  I know they have similar topologies under-the-hood, but it's not clear to the typical SPICE end-user that there is any sort of isolation (the t-line symbol even shows the lines going through).  I suggest clarifying why you decided to talk about transformers, and why transmission lines have similar requirements.

Comment: @SteKulov Good point. I saw T1 and stopped. The author didn't use many words and a transmission line is an "O" device. Not a "T". So despite the symbol I didn't tumble. Now that you bring this up my point remains but words should change. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answere!

Comment: No problem.  Edits look good.  By the way, "O" is for lossy transmission line `ltline` and "T" is for lossless transmission line `tline`.  You used the former and the author used the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to simulate this circuit with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).
Matrix not singular.

Just changed a resistor to 10 Ohm.
If it is 100 Ohm, it is a straight line (because of the generator reflexion coefficient).
See "transmission line" theory for explanations ... or ask.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move the ground reference from the input to the output as shown in the image.
[image]